# How to play video from google drive using react-native-video?

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I want to play a streaming video from my google drive using react-native-video. I got the shareable link and paste in my code, but when i run my code, the log showed an error

> "Couldn't open https://drive.google.com/open?id=1la4ENUiwDvnYbmRck1QZGbKLy8Kc_5UH&name=larva.mp4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1la4ENUiwDvnYbmRck1QZGbKLy8Kc_5UH&name=larva.mp4"

Here is my video code :

```
source={{
uri: 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1la4ENUiwDvnYbmRck1QZGbKLy8Kc_5UH&name=larva.mp4',
type: 'video/mp4'
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the link you provided is a google drive web page with a player which is HTML. And you need a direct resource link to play the video.

You can extract the resource link by using this service `https://gdurl.com/`, paste your link there, and get the permanent resource link.

Change the URL into this will make it work. Enjoy!

```
https://gdurl.com/nUNM
```

Comment: it works, but when I want to share the video with another person it can't play and showed "Access to r5---sn-npoeenez.c.drive.google.com was denied

You don't have authorization to view this page."
I already set the video in my drive public so everyone can view the video. But the inspect link still set private.

Comment: I updated the answer to generate the permanent resource url from google drive @EkoSriWahyuni

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the video is publicly accessible. Just convert Google Drive URL from `https://drive.google.com/file/d/{id}/view` to
`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={id}`
and use it like

```
import Video from "react-native-video";

...

<Video source={{uri: 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={id}'}}
...
```

Just make sure to replace `{id}` with your Google Drive video id.